# Artifactory Remote Repository (Maven Central) - Unauthorized

Tags: repository, artifactory, maven-central

I try to configure Artifactory (2.6.4 rev. 13153) to use Maven Central as a remote repository. For this I configuered the remote repository (please see screenshots below). In gradle.build I configured:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url artifactoryBaseUrl + 'build-libs'
    }
    maven {
        url artifactoryBaseUrl + 'mcentral'
    }
}
```

Using Artifactory's simple browser I can browse Maven Central using my remote repo "mcentral" but when running gradle I get an error:

```
D:\...\at.mic.all.hermes>gradle build
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve org.apache.myfaces.trinidad:trinidad-impl:1.0.13.
Required by:
  at.mic.all.hermes:at.mic.all.hermes:20150924104503

> Could not GET 'http://mic-build2.mic.co.at:8082/artifactory/mcentral/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/trinidad-impl/1.0.13/trinidad-impl-1.0.13.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

BUILD FAILED
```

Any ideas what I made wrong? I would highly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Frank

The screensots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is gradle configured with the right credentials for accessing Artifactory?

Comment: Our local Artifactory allows anonymous downloads, so no credentials are needed. That works fine for artifacts stored in local repositories.

Comment: Can you download this file using cURL? there might a permission target configured which required additional permissions for this repository

Comment: After starting up my windows this morning I read your comment and tried to download the file using firefox... Using Maven Central web GUI - no problem. Using my local Artifactory and the remote repository - authentication needed... At this point I mentioned, that I'm still not logged in in Artifactory after the restart this morning. So I logged in and download works... Seems that our Artifactory is configured to permit anonymously downloads from remote repositories. I hav to take a look at this... Thx for the hint!